# How to aling the data along y-axis in Matlibplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a MWE to explain my issue. As seen in the plot below, the curves are moving along the horizontal axis. I need to force the curves to move along the vertical axis, and set the corresponding ticks on the x-axis.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

employees = np.arange(0, 12, 76)
sub_one_grades = np.random.normal(0, 1, 76) + 10 
sub_two_grades = np.random.normal(0, 1, 76) + 15
sub_three_grades = np.random.normal(0, 1, 76) + 30

# plot
plt.plot(sub_one_grades)
plt.plot(sub_two_grades)
plt.plot(sub_three_grades)

#plt.yticks(employees) #<------REQUIRED, but not working

plt.show()

print()
```

**REQUIRED PLOT:**

[image]

Comment: `employees = np.arange(0, 76)`, `plt.plot(sub_one_grades, employees)`, and so on.

Comment: @BigBen: but `employees = np.arange(0, 12, 76)`. The total number of values in `employees` is equal to the total number of data points in `sub_xx_grades `

Comment: `np.arange(0, 12, 76)` returns `array([0])` and I don't think that's what you want lol. It is most certainly not equal. What are you trying to do with the `12`?

Comment: In any case, you need to swap your x and y data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

employees = np.arange(0, 76)
sub_one_grades = np.random.normal(0, 1, 76) + 10 
sub_two_grades = np.random.normal(0, 1, 76) + 15
sub_three_grades = np.random.normal(0, 1, 76) + 30

#plt.figure(figsize=(12, 30))

plt.plot(sub_one_grades, employees)
plt.plot(sub_two_grades, employees)
plt.plot(sub_three_grades, employees)

#plt.yticks(employees, ['Emp {}'.format(i) for i in employees])
plt.ylabel("Employees")
plt.xlabel("Sub Grades")
plt.show()
```

you can remove # in the code but the plot would look ugly due to high employee amount
[image]

If you uncomment here is what you will get
[image]